# Adding metadata to a Stripe customer object

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am setting up a payment system with Stripe and I would like to add some metadata to the customer object. I would like to add my workspace id to the metadata property of the customer. I tried the below code, but it returns the following error:

```
⛔️ Error:
 Error: Invalid val: {:_bsontype=>"ObjectID", :id=>"\\HÉ\u001E��\u000F�=��"} must be a string under 500 characters
```

I've logged the workspace Id that I add to this metadata property, but it seems like it's just a regular mongodb ObjectId. Can anyone see what I did wrong?

**The code that is supposed to add metadata to the customer I create**

```
    // find the current User and use his workspace ID
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.userId });
    const workspaceId = user._workspace;

    // get the payment plan
    const plan = await stripe.plans.retrieve('plan_EK1uRUJLJcDS6e');

    //   // then we create a new customer
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email,
      source,
      metadata: {
        workspace_id: workspaceId
      }
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'payment complete',
      subscription: adjustedSubscription
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The values you store in `metadata` can only [be strings of up to 500 characters](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata?lang=node). In this case you'd want to parse your `workspaceId` as a string. Looks like you'd want to run `toString()` or [`toHexString()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) on that `ObjectId`.

Comment: Thanks Pual, I added toString() and it works fine now.

Comment: Where exactly did you add .toString()? I'm also getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and found Paul's response. Finally works!

```
router.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
metadata: {
  userId: req.body.userId.toString(),
  cart: JSON.stringify(req.body.cartItems.toString()),
},
```

});