# Stripe invalid value when i proceed to payment

Tags: reactjs, string, stripe-payments

I'm asking for your help with a problem I'm having with Stripe. I'm developing an e-commerce project and I'm having a problem buying the items in the shopping cart. When I have a single item in my cart and I go to checkout, everything goes well. However, when I add more than one item to the cart and try to checkout, I get this error message.

```
Invalid Value: ...must be a string under 500 characters
```

Could you help me solve this problem, please?

I searched a lot on the forums, but I couldn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335044/17985195

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work and it doesn't concern the userId but it concerns the articles I'm trying to pay  ```const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    metadata: {
      uid: req.body.user.uid.toString(),
      panier: JSON.stringify(req.body.panier),
      email: req.body.user.email,
    },
  });```

Comment: So in your customer object we have a bunch of keys, in your case its uid, panier and email.

Their corresponding values are, req.body.user.uid.toString(), JSON.stringify(req.body.panier) and req.body.user.email.

One of these three values are more than 500 characters long and causing this error. It only throws an error when you have multiple items in your shopping cart so the panier is the biggest culprit (i assume that means shopping cart in french)

Comment: Can you try to see if you can store the panier metadata more efficiently instead of JSON stringifying the whole panier (maybe just store the item Ids instead of the req.body.panier?

Comment: wow it works now, i have store the item id as you said and it works great now, thank you very much

Comment: @Boardnerges would appreciate it if you mark my comment as an accepted answer (or thumbs up)